# how to open tracing panel in graphql playground

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

Earlier I have tracing panel in my graphql playground like this picture right bottom corner https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/graphql-playground-3f877c8e310c5ec8a76934d058d511e4.png. Now this panel invisible. How to enable it?

my graphql playground settings:

```
{
  "general.betaUpdates": false,
  "editor.cursorShape": "line",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro', 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Monaco', monospace",
  "editor.theme": "dark",
  "editor.reuseHeaders": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "request.credentials": "omit",
  "tracing.hideTracingResponse": false
}
```

graphql server started file:

```
import * as Express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";

import { createSchema } from "../utils/createSchema";

export default async (app : Express.Application) => {
    const schema = await createSchema();
    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        tracing : true,
        playground: true,
        introspection: true,
        context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({
            req,
            res,
        })
    });

    console.log('Apply Middleware GraphQL');

    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
        app,
        path : '/graphql',
        cors: false
    });

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, but it may be related to this [reported issue](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground/issues/1039)

Comment: thanks to Daniel Rearden. 
issue temporarily resolved by inpust custom style to graphql playground
 
```.
cRrmDs {
    min-height: 0;
}
```
with chrome extention [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld] (user-javascript-and-css)